# Does Tensorflow resize bounding boxes when training an object detection model?

Tags: tensorflow, resize, object-detection

I'm wondering about image resizing and then the intuitive bounding box resizing that would follow that.

For instance, when I use a 640x640 image in my dataset, and the model has a fixed_shape_resizer of 320x320, will the original bounding box be scaled down to match the smaller 320x320 size?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Tensorflow will automatically resize the bounding box to match the smaller input size.

Here is a [Link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/3884688d92669588a1aa337ce2a01dfacd7b056b/research/object_detection/inputs.py#L351-L353) to the code that changes the bounding box sizes.